# Speed up pandas csv read and subsequent downcast

Tags: python, pandas

Straightforward question - I'm doing the following:

```
train_set = pd.read_csv('./input/train_1.csv').fillna(0)
for col in train_set.columns[1:]:
    train_set[col] = pd.to_numeric(train_set[col],downcast='integer')
```

first column of the dataframe is a string - the rest are ints. Read_csv gives floats, which I don't need. The downsampling results in almost 50% reduction in RAM used, but slows the process down significantly. Can I do the whole thing in one step? Or does anybody know how to multithread this?
thx

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you try these two functions and see the performance again:

1. Convert when you read the file

   ```
   # or uint8/int16/int64 depends on your data
   pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep=' ', dtype=np.int32)

   # or you can use converters with lambda function
   pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=' ', converters={'1':lambda x : int(x)})
   ```
2. Convert your dataframe after reading file

   `df['MyColumnName'] = df['MyColumnName'].astype(int)`

Comment: hmm I see the idea, but the problem is that the first line is a string. specifying the dtype in the reading process doesn't work with the string. Would you read them in separately? Can we preserve the order?

Comment: I have edited the code. the converters one also worked for me

Comment: right - the code again works, but doesn't solve the problem. this converts the column with the name '1' to ints. I have the first column as a string and the rest (551 in total) as floats, which I would like to convert.